# Adding a class to a set of li's one at a time with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I've got 5 li's in a ul and a button . On clicking the button I want to add a class to the first li then on the second click remove the class from the first li and add it too the second  ect . I know i could just give each li an individual id but i know there must be a better way and I'll probably want it to be dynamic at some point as well .

thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/PFpaU/

With comments: http://jsfiddle.net/PFpaU/1/

JS:

```
window.change = function() {
    // Select any li which already has the class
    var li = $("li.myclass");
    // If there were any matches...
    if (li.length)
        // Remove the class from the matched li and then move to the
        // next item in the DOM tree, then add the class to that item
        li.removeClass("myclass").next().addClass("myclass");
    else
        // If none of the li's had the class, add it to the first one
        $("li").first().addClass("myclass");
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
<button onclick="change()">Change</button>
```

CSS:

```
.myclass {
     color: #f00;   
}
```

Comment: could you explain the code a little , I'm having trouble with how the next() method works .

Comment: In your code, you don't need to declare the `change` function in the same way I have.  `function change() {` will do fine.  In jsFiddle you have to declare them like that.

Comment: Thanks , so simple but very effective .

Comment: Links to live sites like jsfiddle are a great *adjunct* to an answer, but always put the relevant code **in the answer itself**. External sites can move, go away, etc., rendering the answer precisely useless to anyone else with the same question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code. First, you're selecting the root `<ul>` element (in case multiple exist). Then, search for a list element with your class name, `className` for example. If it exists (`li.length`), remove the class from the current list, and add it to the next one. Otherwise, add the class to the first list element of the `<ul>`.

```
$("#buttonID").click(function(){
    var ul = $("ul"); //Root <ul>, change it to the desired UL, eg #myUL
    var li = $("li.className", ul);
    if(li.length){
        li.removeClass("className").next().addClass("className");
    } else {
        $("li", ul).addClass("className");
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
$('#yourButton').click(function(){
   var ul=$('#yourUlId');
   var next= $('li:not(.yourClass)',ul).first();
   next.addClass('yourClass');
   next.prev().removeClass('yourClass');
});
```

Comment: You're not removing the class as outlined in the question. This also looks at all `li` elements globally, rather than specific to a list.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to refine the selector to something more specific than `li`, but this should do the trick (placed in your click handler).

```
var withClass = $('li .your-class');

if (!withClass.length) {
  // If nothing has the class, add to the first list element
  $('li').addClass('your-class');
} else {
  // Otherwise remove the class and add to the next item
  withClass.removeClass('your-class').next().addClass('your-class');
}
```

Comment: Hi , this add's the class to all the li's .

Comment: Whoops. Of course you're right. The first branch of the if statement should be `$('li').first()`. Everything else should work just fine.